# Query to generate report for different values in a table

Tags: mysql

I'm looking to generate a report where I need to compare records from a mysql table based on a source column, and when the records have different values aside from the source column display the differing records and the status.

For example, given the following table:
[Raw values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJBYM.png)

We would get the following output:

[Report values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUTxE.png)

Joe is shown because for the records for the different sources give different spouses. Bob and Mark are not shown because both sources have the same data for him. Ernest is shown because only one source has his information.

To find the records that exist in one source but are not in the other seems fairly straightforward, something like:

```
SELECT 'New' as `Status`, f.* FROM (select * from tbl where tbl.Source='facebook') where `Name` not in (SELECT `Name` FROM select * from tbl where tbl.Source='linkedin')
```

But i'm a bit lost on how to find records that are different.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identify names that have different job or spouse values on a different source.  Use `UNION ALL` to combine them with the new names which are posted in one source only.

```
select 
'Different' status,
 t1.name,
 t1.job,
 t1.spouse,
 t1.source
FROM 
 tbl t1 
WHERE 
 EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl t2 WHERE t2.name = t1.name AND t2.source <> t1.source AND 
                         (t2.job <> t1.job OR t2.spouse <> t1.spouse ))
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
'New',
 name,
 job,
 spouse,
 source
FROM tbl t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl t2 WHERE t2.name = t1.name
                  AND t2.source <> t1.source );
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was looking for!